# Calculating rotation matrix of coordinate system from 2 known axis

Tags: rotations

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG0QB.png)]

In the image my main coordinate system is in the upper right corner. I measured $3$ points on a board and created a help coordinate system. V1 points directly to the origin of the help coordinate system. V2 and V3 lie on different axis of the help coordinate system.

I want to find the transformation matrix.
So V1 is my translation, right?
Subtracting V1 from V2 and V3 I can move the origin of the help coordinate system to the origin of the main coordinate system, right?

But how do I calculate the rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a set of three orthogonal vectors from the following:

$$u_1 = v_2 - v_1$$
$$u_3 = u_1 \times (v_3 - v_1)$$
$$u_2 = u_3 \times u_1$$

Once you normalize all three of these vectors you can construct the rotation matrix as follows:

$$\mathbf R = [u_1\ u_2 \ u_3]$$

This is what I have referred to as a *triad*, although I am not sure how common that terminology is.

Comment: Thank you very much! That turned out a lot simpler than I thought...

Comment: @Tpofofn could you please check my question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599061/how-to-calculate-the-transformation-matrix-if-the-coordinate-system-translates-a/3601670?noredirect=1#comment7404018_3601670 thank you

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, looks like it has already been answered.

Comment: yes , in the meantime. Thank you !