# how to calculate the transformation matrix if the coordinate system translates and rotates?

Tags: linear-transformations, rotations

I was trying to calculate the new coordinates of the 4 corners of the rectangle in the image, but I think I only formed the rotation matrix. what is the correct transformation matrix for this operation ?
this is the triangle and the points names in order
[image]

and here is my calculations in Excel , attention that coefficient is only used to determine the sign of X and Y displacement of the origin, I tried both ±1. a=10 and b=5

using this transformation matrix

[image]

I don't get the expected results :

[image]

Comment: To include a translation in a transformation matrix, you need to use homogeneous coordinates. Do you know about those? If not, then any translation has to be handled separately from the _linear_ part of the transformation, which can be encoded in a matrix.

Comment: I used this link : https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html and was trying to do that in Excel, but I was not successfull. I do not get the expected results

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to include your attempts at solving the problem. Some more details would be helpful, such as where exactly is the origin relative to the rectangle after the transformation? Also, I’d recommend trying to do the calculation by hand so that it’s easier to tell if you’re getting some of the concepts wrong of just have a bug in your spreadsheet implementation of it.

Comment: the new origin is exactly at the center of the rectangle

Comment: does this help?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523274/matrix-for-rotation-and-translation-along-its-local-axis/3530859

Comment: no, I used those formulas, now I edited my question , please check above, even for this simple case, I did not get a good answer

Comment: @amd what do you think?

Comment: so now any ideas ?

Comment: the matrix multiplication is correct, I just don't understand where have I gone wrong. cause visually , it should have the expected new coordinates, but calcuation says different

Comment: I am still hoping for an answer

Comment: @amd am I doing a mistake that I'm not noticing or there's no answer?

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail! It makes your error very easy to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to use the inverse of the transformation matrix in your question.

You’ve made a fairly common error here. The transformation matrix that you’ve shown maps the old coordinate axes onto the new ones. However, to get the coordinates of a point relative to these new axes, you have to invert that transformation. Why this is so is covered elsewhere on this SE and on the Internet, but I’ll briefly explain why here.

Let $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ be the positive unit direction vectors of an arbitrary pair of coordinate axes, and $O$ the origin point of this coordinate system. We can express any point as $u\mathbf U+v\mathbf V+O$; the coefficients $u$ and $v$ are the coordinates of this point in this coordinate system. The $x$- and $y$- coordinates in the standard coordinate system can be understood in the same way by taking $\mathbf X=(1,0)$ and $\mathbf Y=(0,1)$, so that we have $x\mathbf X+y\mathbf Y$. We can write $\mathbf U=a\mathbf X+b\mathbf Y$ and $\mathbf V=c\mathbf X+d\mathbf Y$, and if we express $O$ as coordinates in the standard coordinate system, we get the following identity: $$x\mathbf X+y\mathbf Y = u(a\mathbf X+b\mathbf Y)+v(c\mathbf X+d\mathbf Y)+O.$$ Using homogeneous coordinates, we can express this identity in matrix form as $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a&c&O_x\\b&d&O_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Note that the $3\times3$ matrix in this identity maps the standard unit coordinate vectors onto the new ones and sends the origin to $O$. We want to solve this equation for $u$ and $v$, which we can do by multiplying both sides by the inverse of the $3\times3$ matrix.

In your case, $\mathbf X$ gets sent to $-\mathbf Y=(0,-1,0)$, $\mathbf Y$ gets sent to $\mathbf X=(1,0,0)$, and the origin gets sent to $(a/2,b/2)$. The correct matrix for computing the new coordinates of a point is therefore $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&\frac a2\\-1&0&\frac b2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&\frac b2\\1&0&-\frac a2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ More generally, if the new coordinate axes are obtained by rotating and translating the old ones, the coordinate transformation matrix will be $$\begin{bmatrix}R&\mathbf t\\\mathbf 0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}R^T&-R^T\mathbf t\\\mathbf 0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta&-(b_1\cos\theta+b_2\sin\theta)\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&-(b_2\cos\theta-b_1\sin\theta)\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Here I used the fact that the inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

Comment: now if I have to rotate my points in the new coordinates, what is the transformation matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really comment due to reputation but, can you please include the details: what exactly you're trying to do and include a grid of reference to denote the transformation you're trying to achieve(or atleast the position of origin) and label the vertices of the image in the rectangle. I'll try to help you further then. e.g. an explanation like rotating the rectangle and translating via xyz.

Comment: why is my question not clear ? I don't understand. I have labled the vertices, did you check the rectangle on the left ? the question is simply : What are the new coordinates of the 4 vertices if you rotate and dispalce the coordinate system as depicted ?

Comment: I am not much familiar with excel but, as I see it you do a -90 i.e. a clockwise 90 deg rotation, but here you say: "if you rotate and displace the _coordinate system_ then", say if `T` is the transformation you're performing, then if you do this `T` for your _coordinate system_ then you find out the vertex position of the _object_ doing a  `inverse T` transformation on your object. which might be the cause the answer is not matching

Comment: I did not understand at all. May you clarify please ?

Comment: I wonder if you do openGL? It's a viewport - camera transformation when you do what you have done above. basically imagine you're seeing through a camera and imagine the director telling you to move the camera but it's glued with super glue ;-) He's gonna fire you if you don't move the camera 20cm to the right. So, to save your job you ask the actors to move 20cm to the left instead. See. :-) you can't move the frame(rectangle) right, so you move the world(actors) left. :-)

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti : more on transformations : https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems

Comment: if you check the Excel screenshot, above the origin displacement variables of X and Y , there is a value -1. which determines the sign of the movement. what you say is exactly what I have done. I also changed the angle to 90 but the results are not correct